# jointModel from JM throws unclear error message

Tags: r, package, survival-analysis

I´m trying to fit longitudinal time to event data with a joint model using the R-package "JM". This is my first attempt with joint models and follows a textbook approach:

```
aids.id <- aids[!duplicated(aids$patient),]
lmeFit.aids <- lme(CD4~obstime + obstime:drug, random=~obstime|patient, data=aids)
coxFit.aids <- coxph(Sdurv(Time,death)~drug,data=aids.id, x=TRUE)
jointFit.aids <- jointModel(lmeFit.aids, coxFit.aids, timeVar="obstime",method="piecewise-PH-aGH")
summary(jointFit.aids)
```

The code works as expected. But when I use my own data, it doesn't work anymore.

str(DATA)
'data.frame':   6436 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ patnr     : Factor w/ 1669 levels "0010000158","0010000278",..: 4 4 4 4 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...

$ sex       : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

$ date      : POSIXct, format: "2008-08-08" "2010-01-25" "2012-02-24" "2012-04-21" ...

$ time      : num  1355 1355 1355 1355 834 ...

$ Crea      : num  7.4 9.6 12.3 10.3 0.8 ...

$ CysC      : num  6.2 5.84 6.17 5.32 0.9 0.94 0.92 0.91 0.91 0.91 ...

$ deathdate : POSIXct, format: "2012-04-24" "2012-04-24" "2012-04-24" "2012-04-24" ...

$ start_date: POSIXct, format: "2008-08-08" "2008-08-08" "2008-08-08" "2008-08-08" ...

$ stop_date : POSIXct, format: "2010-01-25" "2012-02-24" "2012-04-21" "2012-04-24" ...

$ start     : num  0 535 1295 1352 0 ...

$ stop      : num  535 1295 1352 1355 3 ...

$ obstime   : num  0 535 1295 1352 0 ...

$ event     : num  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

These are the first 20 lines of the data frame:

```
          patnr sex       date       time  Crea CysC  deathdate start_date  stop_date      start       stop    obstime event
637  0010000343   1 2008-08-08 1355.00000  7.40 6.20 2012-04-24 2008-08-08 2010-01-25    0.00000  535.04167    0.00000     0
816  0010000343   1 2010-01-25 1355.00000  9.60 5.84 2012-04-24 2008-08-08 2012-02-24  535.04167 1295.04167  535.04167     0
1171 0010000343   1 2012-02-24 1355.00000 12.31 6.17 2012-04-24 2008-08-08 2012-04-21 1295.04167 1352.00000 1295.04167     0
1201 0010000343   1 2012-04-21 1355.00000 10.35 5.32 2012-04-24 2008-08-08 2012-04-24 1352.00000 1355.00000 1352.00000     1
1363 0010000873   1 2011-12-05  834.00000  0.80 0.90       <NA> 2011-12-05 2011-12-08    0.00000    3.00000    0.00000     0
1370 0010000873   1 2011-12-08  834.00000  0.52 0.94       <NA> 2011-12-05 2011-12-09    3.00000    4.00000    3.00000     0
1372 0010000873   1 2011-12-09  834.00000  0.45 0.92       <NA> 2011-12-05 2011-12-18    4.00000   13.00000    4.00000     0
1386 0010000873   1 2011-12-18  834.00000  0.34 0.91       <NA> 2011-12-05 2011-12-19   13.00000   14.00000   13.00000     0
1387 0010000873   1 2011-12-19  834.00000  0.31 0.91       <NA> 2011-12-05 2011-12-20   14.00000   15.00000   14.00000     0
1391 0010000873   1 2011-12-20  834.00000  0.62 0.91       <NA> 2011-12-05 2011-12-27   15.00000   22.00000   15.00000     0
1411 0010000873   1 2011-12-27  834.00000  0.61 1.44       <NA> 2011-12-05 2011-12-31   22.00000   26.00000   22.00000     0
1418 0010000873   1 2011-12-31  834.00000  0.43 1.18       <NA> 2011-12-05 2012-01-01   26.00000   27.00000   26.00000     0
1419 0010000873   1 2012-01-01  834.00000  0.46 1.22       <NA> 2011-12-05 2013-07-09   27.00000  581.95833   27.00000     0
1466 0010000873   1 2013-07-09  834.00000  0.85 0.91       <NA> 2011-12-05 2014-03-18  581.95833  834.00000  581.95833     0
1478 0010000873   1 2014-03-18  834.00000  1.20 1.00       <NA> 2011-12-05 2015-09-18  834.00000 1382.95833  834.00000     0
2020 0010002412   1 2015-03-26   23.95833  1.16 0.85       <NA> 2015-03-26 2015-04-10    0.00000   14.95833    0.00000     0
2035 0010002412   1 2015-04-10   23.95833  0.67 0.74       <NA> 2015-03-26 2015-04-14   14.95833   18.95833   14.95833     0
2043 0010002412   1 2015-04-14   23.95833  0.56 0.75       <NA> 2015-03-26 2015-04-16   18.95833   20.95833   18.95833     0
2046 0010002412   1 2015-04-16   23.95833  0.45 0.75       <NA> 2015-03-26 2015-04-17   20.95833   21.95833   20.95833     0
2049 0010002412   1 2015-04-17   23.95833  0.52 0.86       <NA> 2015-03-26 2015-04-18   21.95833   22.95833   21.95833     0
```

This is the code I used:

```
copd.id <- DATA[!duplicated(DATA$patnr),]
copd.id$event <- as.numeric(!is.na(copd.id$deathdate))

lmeFit.copd <- lme(CysC~obstime+obstime:sex, random=~obstime|patnr, data=DATA)
coxFit.copd <- coxph(Surv(time,event)~sex, data=copd.id, x=TRUE)
jointFit.copd <- jointModel(lmeFit.copd, coxFit.copd, timeVar="obstime",method="piecewise-PH-aGH")

summary(jointFit.copd)
```

And I get the following error message:

> > jointFit.copd <- jointModel(lmeFit.copd, coxFit.copd, timeVar="obstime",method="piecewise-PH-aGH") Fehler in
> >     jointModel(lmeFit.copd, coxFit.copd, timeVar = "obstime", method =
> >     "piecewise-PH-aGH") :     it seems that there are longitudinal
> >     measurements taken after the event times for some subjects (i.e.,
> >     check subject(s): 0010000343, 0010000695, 0010000873, 0010002412,
> >     0010002782, 0010003305, 0010003865, 0010003975, 0010004179,
> >     0010004534, 0010004943, 0010005724, 0010007075, 0010007495,
> >     0010008083, 0010008279, 0010008488, 0010008692, 0010008751,
> >     0010009439, 0010010330, 0010011663, 0010012262, 0010012543,
> >     0010012575, 0010013477, 0010014195, 0010015876, 0010016684,
> >     0010017677, 0010018443, 0010019213, 0010019403, 0010019646,
> >     0010020446, 0010020695, 0010021115, 0010021159, 0010021916,
> >     0010022698, 0010024937, 0010026652, 0010030656, 0010031115,
> >     0010031654, 0010031760, 0010033685, 0010034046, 0010034303,
> >     0010035140, 0010037655, 0010038043, 0010038117, 0010038168,
> >     0010038622, 0010039907, 0010042346, 0010044178, 0010046528,
> >     0010046756, 0010048385, 0010049308, 0010049625, 0010049854,
> >     0010050309, 0010051869, 0010052193, 0010052645, 0010052927,
> >     0010053024, 0010054182, 0010055882, 001
> >
> > summary(jointFit.copd) Fehler in summary(jointFit.copd) : Objekt 'jointFit.copd' nicht gefunden

The thing is: I checked the data, and there are no measurements after the events.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are the first 20 lines sufficient to get that error????

Comment: What is Your angle at this? Do You think there are single cases causing the error? How much data do You need?

Comment: Talking to the designer of the package JM, I made sure, that
1) no event times are zero
2) last measurement != censoring/event time
3) no measurement times after event time
4) model is set to TRUE in coxph()
5) no missing data
6) time scales are equal
Still can´t find any hint on the error message...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try sorting `DATA` on `patnr` before running the models.  I can induce the error you get for your `DATA` in the `aids` example by making a `newid` that is not sorted.

```
library(JM)
is.unsorted(aids$patient)
length(unique(aids$patient))
##  make newid that is unsorted
no.rows <- rle(c(aids$patient))
aids$newid <- paste0(rep( rep(LETTERS, length.out=467), no.rows$lengths), aids$patient)
is.unsorted(aids$newid)
length(unique(aids$newid))
## change `patient` to newid in the following lines to get 
## error message for `jointFit.aids`
aids.id <- aids[!duplicated(aids$patient),]
lmeFit.aids <- lme(CD4~obstime + obstime:drug, random=~obstime|newid, data=aids)
coxFit.aids <- coxph(Surv(Time,death)~drug,data=aids.id, x=TRUE)
jointFit.aids <- jointModel(lmeFit.aids, coxFit.aids, timeVar="obstime",method="piecewise-PH-aGH")
summary(jointFit.aids)
```

This came to mind when I looked at the [code for JM on github](https://github.com/drizopoulos/JM/blob/a9628ee4f5691a63951e6e8bbb2df3d7475e2b51/R/jointModel.R).  Since the error message is printed at line 139 in jointModel.R, I looked at how things were defined above that line and came to the conclusion that assumptions are made about the dataset being sorted on the id variable.  So while it is true that no subject in `DATA` violates the condition, the order gets scrambled up in the code.  In the absence of a reproducible example, my first hint was that the first 20 lines of the dataset given in the question had IDs 0010000343, 0010000873, 0010002412, but the error message posted lists the ids in sorted order had 0010000343, **0010000695**, 0010000873, 0010002412 -- indicating that `DATA` is not sorted on the id  variable (`patnr`) that is listed in the `lme()` model.  The original `aids` example is sorted on id (`patient`).

Comment: I never thought of this, but You are perfectly right. Well earned 50 points indeed. I used:
sortnames <- c("patnr","date")     
DATA <- DATA[do.call("order", DATA[sortnames]),]     
to sort the data and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Very well earned 50 points.a %>% arrange(id,t) at the end of one of my dplyr chains solved this issue. I'd never have thought of that in a million years.